# Failed convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long' nested excep java.lang.NumberFormatException For input string "null"

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have this error and not sure what what else to trouble shoot. I am just trying to have a user click an "rsvp" button and have it register to the database along with the user id that hit the button. Every time I click on the button it takes me to the url /event/null . Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Event.java:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "event_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user;
    
    private String message;
    
    @JoinTable(name = "rsvp_status", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id"))
    private Boolean rsvp = false;
    
    
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;

    
    
    public Event() {}
    
    
    
    
    public Event(User user, String message, Boolean rsvp, Date createdAt) {
        this.user = user;
        this.message = message;
        this.rsvp = rsvp;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }




    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


    public Boolean getRsvp() {
        return rsvp;
    }


    public void setRsvp(Boolean rsvp) {
        this.rsvp = rsvp;
    }




    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Event [id=" + id + ", user=" + user + ", message=" + message + ", rsvp=" + rsvp + ", createdAt="
                + createdAt + "]";
    }
}
```

EventService:

```
@Service
public class EventService {
    
    @Autowired
    private EventRepository eventRepository;
    
    @Autowired 
    UserService userService;

    
    public Event findEventById(Long id) {
        Optional<Event> optionalEvent = eventRepository.findById(id);
        
        Event event = null;
        
        if(optionalEvent.isPresent()) {
            event = optionalEvent.get();
            return event;
        } else {
            return event;
        }
    }
    
    public List<EventDisplay> findAll() {
        List<Event> events = eventRepository.findAllByOrderByCreatedAtDesc();
        return formatEvents(events);
    }
        
    public List<EventDisplay> findAllByUser(User user) {
        List<Event> events = eventRepository.findAllByUserOrderByCreatedAtDesc(user);
        return formatEvents(events);
    }
        
    public List<EventDisplay> findAllByUsers(List<User> users){
        List<Event> events = eventRepository.findAllByUserInOrderByCreatedAtDesc(users);
        return formatEvents(events);
    }
    
    public void save (Event event) {
        eventRepository.save(event);
    }


    private List<EventDisplay> formatEvents(List<Event> events) {
        List<EventDisplay> displayEvents = formatTimestamps(events);
        return displayEvents;
    }

    private List<EventDisplay> formatTimestamps(List<Event> events) {
        List<EventDisplay> response = new ArrayList<>();
        PrettyTime prettyTime = new PrettyTime();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDate = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yy");
        Date now = new Date();
        for (Event event : events) {
            EventDisplay eventDisplay = new EventDisplay();
            eventDisplay.setUser(event.getUser());
            eventDisplay.setMessage(event.getMessage());
            long diffInMillies = Math.abs(now.getTime() - event.getCreatedAt().getTime());
            long diff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diffInMillies, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            if (diff > 3) {
                eventDisplay.setDate(simpleDate.format(event.getCreatedAt()));
            } else {
                eventDisplay.setDate(prettyTime.format(event.getCreatedAt()));
            }
            response.add(eventDisplay);
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Rsvp Controller:

```
@Controller
public class RsvpController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    @Autowired
    EventService eventService;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/event/{id}")
    public String rsvp(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam String submit, Event event, HttpServletRequest request,
            Model model) {
        //getting the event by Id
        Event eventToRsvp = eventService.findEventById(id);
        if(submit.equals("up")) {
            if(eventToRsvp != null) {
                event.setRsvp(true);
                eventService.save(event);
            } 
            
        }
        return "redirect:" + request.getHeader("Referer");
    }
}
```

Events.html:

```
<form  th:action="@{/event/} + ${eventToRsvp}" method = "post">
                    <button style="float: right;" type="Submit" value="up"
                        class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">RSVP</button>
                </form>
```

The error in my console Log:

```
2021-03-29 18:08:21.511  WARN 17584 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"]
```

Comment: Could you point out which line this error is occurring on?

Comment: Not sure what specific line, but the error occurs when I click the RSVP button on my front-end.

Comment: From the error it looks like your `${eventToRsvp}` variable is set to null and it is sending to controller where it try to convert 'null' string to Long and hence failing.. make sure you are sending proper value in `${eventToRsvp}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error may be coming from your `rsvp()` method. For `@PathVariable Long id`, it's expecting a `Long` type but you're passing in a `String` type. You can do `Long.parseLong(id)` to convert the `String` into a `Long`. It also looks like you're passing in a `String` representation of `"null"` into this `id`? Let me know what you get after fixing the first error, though.

Comment: Doing the Long.parseLong(id) - gives me an error. Do you mean I should change the return type of the method? My apologies

Comment: Yes, you can try that.

Comment: Okay I changed the return type to void and it still is giving me that same error so it's reading a String somewhere within the method. My understanding when you have a @PathVariable & the argument next to it, that's what it reads within the URL path so not sure why it keeps trying to read a String.

Comment: Did you change the arg type of `findEventById(Long id)` to `String id`?

Comment: Just did that, had me implement a method inside of the repository for the new "String id". Now it's giving me Required String parameter 'submit' is not present. The URL when I click the button still brings me to /events/null. Interesting lol

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is in `th:action` url.Try

```
th:action="@{'/event/' + ${eventToRsvp}}"
```

Or
path variable can be passed from thymeleaf page to controller method by placing double underscore around it.

```
th:action="@{/event/__${eventToRsvp}__}"
```